# .NET MAUI project properties is not loading in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022, maui

I have created a .NET MAUI application with Visual Studio 2022 on Windows and when I do right click on .NET MAUI project in Solution Explorer and navigate to Project Settings, the UI editor tries to initialize and stucks in a screen saying "Loading Properties...". I am waiting for a few minutes and nothing happens. I also tried to reproduce in a new project and  I have the same behavior. I also tried in Visual Studio 2022 (Preview) and same behavior here. I have updated both Visual Studio 2022 (Professional & Preview) and I have the same behavior. Any ideas why this happens ?

The only time project settings worked was only I accidently opened the Android manifest file. Then I tried to reproduced it again and nothing happens.

[image]

Comment: Try creating a MAUI application, don't edit it in any way, but run it. Does it work?

Comment: I have just created a new .NET MAUI App. I run it and it works fine on my physical device. When I try then to open project settings the problem still exists. I have not edit it at all.

Comment: I have rebooted the Windows machine but nothing changed. I tried to reproduce the issue on another Windows machine running Visual Studio 2022 (the previous stable version and worked). My Windows machine runs Visual Studio 2022 (Preview) v17.4.0 Preview 5.0 and Visual Studio 2022 Professional 17.3.6

Comment: Something is very wrong. First, make sure you have lots of disk space. If you do, next Disable everything that runs when Windows starts up - in case there is some weird conflict (though I haven't heard of any), and reboot pc. If still does not work, restore your startup settings, and delete all copies of Visual Studio 2022 (stable and preview), reboot pc, install "stable" again.